# Install and Refence Tao Framework on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tao-framework

I'm Trying to get the Tao Framework going in my system. I have Windows 7 64bit With Visual Studio 2010.

I have downloaded the file "taoframework-2.1.0-setup.exe" and installed it, leaving everything as it was.

As far as I understand now i should be able to add either a "Tool" in the toolbox that will be called simpleOpen GL or to add a "Reference" in a specific project.

The problem is that nothing related to Tao Framework is showing in my visual studio.

I've been reading around and haven't found any solid answers, a tutorial would be nice, any info will help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about OpenTK? Apparently Tao has been superseded by OpenTK. The last release of Tao was in 2008.

http://www.opentk.com/

Comment: I guess I will have to give it a try... I was trying to install Tao because the book I'm following asks for it

Answer (score 1):

You have to search for it. Right click in the toolbox and click "choose items". in VS2010 the option will not appear on the dialog box so you click browse and go to installation folder(C:\Program Files\TaoFramework\bin) of Tao framework and look for Tao.Platform.Windows.dll.

Then click ok and will see the simpleOpenGLControl and the click ok. It will be loaded as part of the toolbox